# Would putting a grenade down the barrel of the tank really blow up the cockpit?

Tags: the-walking-dead, weapon

In The Walking Dead, [S4E8: Too Far Gone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948638/), Daryl takes a grenade and tosses it down the barrel of a tank.  After a few seconds when you hear it bouncing around, some people abandon the cockpit and then it explodes.

Would that actually happen?  It seems like a pretty flawed design if something hostile could make its way in and do that.  Obviously it's a completely different machine, but in a semi-automatic pistol, for example, a foreign thing would never be able to make its way completely through the barrel because a round is already loaded in the chamber.

So is this just cinematic drama?

Comment: i dont believe that the grande would actually enter the inside of the tank, as the tanks gun has a loading chamber similar to a gun in which its closed unless currently being loaded. the grenade at the back end of the barrel though would probably still do considerable damage inside of the tank.

Comment: Boom. It turns out that this is not only feasible but that it's been tried in combat conditions. The perpetrators of this act of insane valor were kind enough to film the results for us.

Comment: I have no idea which side these guys are on. I just hope that I'm never on the other side.

Comment: @asteri I VTC'd, then retracted; Reason: I at first thought that an out-of-world explanation to an in-world situation should not be on-topic here, but after thinking about it, the in-world is supposedly exactly the same as ours, except with Zombies/Walkers/Undead etc., therefore, any real-world explanation will hold true in-world when it comes to tanks etc...

Comment: @Mooz Hey, I'm all about the crowdsourcing and the wisdom of the masses.  If you think it's off-topic, vote with your heart, sir.  Same for the guy who said that the physics aren't relevant here.

Comment: I VTC'd and retracted. It's not a good fit but there was a readily available answer and the question was prompted by a science fiction show.

Comment: Just because there's an answer doesn't make it on-topic! This is a classic scientific explanation question.

Comment: @mooz There is one other difference between this world and ours. The show exists in a parallel universe where zombies never existed in thier pop-culture.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero Good pick up!

Comment: This question is perfectly relevant because the OP is attempting to validate a scene from a world where zombies exist. This is what we do here. No different than how a lightsaber works.

Comment: With the type of grenade Daryl used, no this is 100% not possible.  Daryl tossed a frag grenade into the tank.  Frag grenades do not cause incendiary type effects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. It's perfectly possible...

Comment: Wow... I... I just... no part of me ever thought something like this would be filmed and on YouTube.  Haha.  Well played, sir.

Comment: I guess the round in the tank has to be manually loaded or something...?

Comment: @asteri - Not a clue. If  had to guess, the first grenade cleared the breech and the second one rolled right into the tank

Comment: i think typically theres a guy in their opening the chamber and reloading the tank (at least in Indian Jones and the last crusade they did) haha and even in the grenade technically doesn't go inside of the actually cockpit the grenade will still roll down the shaft and be "inside" of the tank and blow up.

Comment: This scene coming soon to a city near you...

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, it's possible.

However, if the barrel is empty and the breach is closed, the breach should be sturdy enough to contain the explosion and direct it back up the barrel (grenades don't actually hold much explosive - most of the damage is from the shrapnel. This how "throwing yourself on a grenade" has saved lives).

Now, there's two other ways this could go - and that's where things get more interesting:

1. The breach is closed and the barrel is loaded. The exploding grenade will likely cook off the charge used to fire the shell. The shell will then foul on the grenade's shrapnel, and could explode in the barrel. Even so, with the shell fouling, there will be an overpressure from the charge cooking off, and this could cause failure in the barrel or breach.
2. The breach happens to be open while reloading (most likely in this scenario, as the tank crew might not even notice the grenade being posted if it didn't drop out of the breach into the compartment). The grenade goes off, and there are lots of shells and cartridges in there waiting to be loaded. Secondary explosions occur, and boom - off goes the turret.